# Как подсчитать количество строк в базе данных?

Tags: mysqli, база-данных, php

нужно подсчитать количество непрочитаных сообщений в базе даннных.

```
$link = connectDB(); 
$queryString = "SELECT COUNT(msg_id) FROM `cms_messages` WHERE `to_user`='".USER_ID."' AND `read`= 0";

$result = $link->query($queryString);

$r = $result->field_count;
$result = $result == true ? $r : "error msg count" ;
return $result;
```

постоянно выдает 1 или NULL.

Comment: 1. что такое `$result->field_count;`?
2. сделайте `SELECT COUNT(msg_id) as cnt_mess FROM ...` и обращайтесь как к обычному полю

Comment: а SQL запросы в MySQL и MySQLi Разные????

Comment: @jcmax настолько же разные, насколько необходимо ставить четыре вопросительных знака.

Comment: >> постоянно выдает 1 или NULL. 
потому и 1, что у тебя запрос возвращает единственную строку с результатом подсчета, т.е. тебе надо выводить не количество строк в результате, а поле результата, как правильно заметил вышеотписавшийся, либо переделать запрос, например, так:
    SELECT msg_id FROM `cms_m`...

Comment: выкинь комп в окошко)))

Comment: @jcmax, откуда мы вообще знаем, что этот код должен делать?  
@Dreamchild, ты б хоть верстку поправил прежде чем комментарием делать  
@Deus вам на яплакал

Comment: @Fike, цитата из его же коммента:"

    Объясните мне как барану, что у меня здесь не так, а то я сейчас наверно выкину комп в окошко"

Я ответил адекватно!

Comment: @Deus, я не настолько дебил, как вам кажется.

Comment: @Fike в данный момент я с телефона, а потому ковыряться в верстке нет ни желания, ни возможности. И потом, если вас не затруднит, то давайте не будем тыкать, мы же с вами культурные и воспитанные люди, я надеюсь.

Comment: он банально должен выполнять Query Запросы которые в переменной, а вместо это выдает ошибки, Там написано if т.е. если бы Query не правильные были то он бы проходил мимо, а он, не проходит и при это выдает вот такую ошибку: Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object.

Comment: @jcmax, просто напросто - разберитесь в коде. Сообщение об ошибке - это путь  к ее исправлению. Где-то там в коде вы обратились к несуществующему экземпляру класса или что-то типа этого... Это ж элементарно, Ватсон!

Comment: Это потому, что 

    if($res = $link->query($queryString))
        $res->close();

в $res не обязательно будет объект, может быть и bool. Конкретно в вашем случае там будет TRUE, т.к. вы используете UPDATE $tbl_name SET ...! Учим матчасть!!!
**mixed** mysqli::query ( string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
**mixed** говорит о том, что параметр может принимать много (но необязательно все) типов.

Comment: @MDJHD, вы озадачили ТС своим комментарием!

Comment: @MDJHD, конкретно в случае ТС там будет mysqli_result, а не TRUE.  

> В случае успешного выполнения запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE или EXPLAIN mysqli_query() вернет объект mysqli_result. 

И только 

> Для остальных успешных запросов mysqli_query() вернет TRUE.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, внимательно прочитайте коммент ТС и заметите

    .....
    else { $queryString = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET time='$time',info='".serialize($data)."' WHERE session='".$session."'"; 
    }
    if($res = $link->query($queryString))
        $res->close();
    }

Здесь как раз этот случай :)

    Для остальных успешных запросов mysqli_query() вернет TRUE.

Comment: @MDJHD, а! вы про ту кашу в комментарии, которая к вопросу отношения не имеет. Не думал, что у кого-то хватит желания разбираться в таком "коде". принято.

Answer (score 2):

По второму вопросу. Почему 1 или NULL.
Внимательно читаем http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.field-count.php

> Возвращает число столбцов...

Число столбцов в вашем запросе равно 1. Это если что-то вообще возвращается. Если выборка пустая, то число столбцов будет равно нулю (NULL).

По первому вопросу. Посчитать количество строк, только не в базе, а в таблице.
У вас "почти" правильно.

```
$link = connectDB(); 
$queryString = "SELECT COUNT(msg_id) FROM `cms_messages` WHERE `to_user`='".USER_ID."' AND `read`= 0";

if ($result = $link->query($queryString)){
  if ($result->num_rows!=0) {
    $r = $result->fetch_array()[0];
  } else {
    $r = "no records";
  }
  $result->close();
} else {
  $r = "query failed";
}
$link->close();
return $r;
```

Comment: ok! Спасибо завтра посмотрю сегодня чето башка уже не варит